# SQL fetch data returns all values

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query

```
select *  from table8 where dept='Mechanical' and date between '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-26' and  status='Completed' or status='Pending'
```

it returns other dept values

Comment: Is this the full query? Because I see no problem in that.

Comment: query seems fine, what kind of values does it return?

Comment: as Raging Bull is saying, is there anything else in the where clause?

Comment: @NaveenRajan: Did the above query return records with Country other than 'Germany' and 'Mexico'? It might be some typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OR` operator has lower precedence than `AND`. See MySQL operator precedence rules e.g. [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

So it all works correctly, but then you do `or status='Pending'` and it will also return rows which just have pending status.

Use parentheses to clarify the precedence, in particular:

```
... and (status='Completed' or status='Pending')
```